# `backspace` in gfortran (old and new)

Tags: io, fortran, gfortran

Suppose I want to append a line to a file in Fortran.  Using a recent version (4.7) of `gfortran`, I find that this works:

```
program test
  integer :: lun=10, i=0

  open(FILE='test.dat', UNIT=lun)

  do
     read(lun, *, END=20) i
     print *, i
  end do
20 backspace(lun)

  write(lun, *), i+1
end program test
```

In `gfortran 4.4` however, it *overwrites* the last line.  To *append*, I find I need to use

```
20 continue
```

instead of `backspace`.

What is up with that?  How would you handle this in a real program?

Comment: seems like simply incorrect behvavior in 4.4. per standard "if the preceding record is an endfile record, the file becomes positioned before the endfile record.".

Comment: fwiw, an old g77 (3.4.6) behaves as expected (not overwriting), while gfortran 4.1.2 overwrites. Both work properly using open append (though the g77 needs access= instead of position= )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
program test
  integer :: lun=10, i=0,io

  open(FILE='test.dat', UNIT=lun, POSITION="append")

  backspace(lun,iostat=io)

  if (io==0) then
    read(lun,*) i
  else
    i = 0
  end if

  write(lun, *) i+1

end program test
```